# Why are there absolute jmps in disassembly of position independent code?

Tags: assembly, osx, mach-o, macos, pie

I'm playing around with Hopper and am looking at the disassembly of a binary that `otool` reports as having the `PIE` flag.

It's my understanding that as a result, the executable base address will be randomized, and so jumps have to be relative to the current instruction pointer.

However, looking at the output of this PIE binary in Hopper, I see absolute jumps like so:

```
00000001000021df    mov      rbx, rax
00000001000021e2    test     rbx, rbx
00000001000021e5    je       0x1000021c0
```

Is Hopper just translating the relative jumps into an absolute jump assuming the text segment is loaded at the standard virtual address of `0x100000000`, or am I missing something conceptual with regards to how position independent executables work?

Comment: Mind to attach the corresponding opcodes? The hexbytes which represent the instructions.

Comment: Hopper reports that the instruction at 0x1000021e5 is encoded as `74 D9` @Megabeets . I see that this corresponds to a relative jump according to the intel reference. I'm guessing then that Hopper is just converting the relative jump into its equivalent for easy viewing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in your comment, the corresponding opcode to `je 0x1000021c0` is `74 D9`. Thus, there's no doubt that you are facing a relative JMP. Hopper is translating the relative JMP so it'll be easier for a reverse engineer to understand the flow of the code without having to calculate addresses.

I'll demonstrate what Hopper does with a simple example using radare2 (although you can use your favorite tool to do the same).

First, we'll open radare2 with 10000 empty bytes allocated in `rwx` permissions so we'll have a "sandbox" to play in:

```
$ r2 malloc://10000
```

Since our base address is `0x00000000` we'll seek (go to) to `0x000021e5` so it'll be easier for us to see the relative jump:

```
[0x00000000]> s 0x21e5
[0x000021e5]>
```

See how our current address changed to `0x21e5`? good !

Now, let's write our hex-bytes (`74 d9`) in the current address:

```
[0x000021e5]> wx 74d9
```

And disassemble one instruction in this address:

```
[0x000021e5]> pd 1
        ╰─< 0x000021e5      74d9           je 0x21c0
```

As you can see, radare2, as Hopper does, translated the jump in address`0x????21e5` to `je 0x????21c0`.

Answer (score 1):

well megabeets was faster 
here is how to check it in windbg

```
0:000> ? .
Evaluate expression: 1999570342 = 772f05a6
0:000> EB . 74 D9
0:000> U . L1
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
772f05a6 74d9            je      ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x7 (772f0581)
0:000> ? 772F0581 - .
Evaluate expression: -37 = ffffffdb
0:000> ? 21E5-21C0
Evaluate expression: 37 = 00000025
0:000>
```